# Google Optimize with relative paths

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, ab-testing, google-optimize

Trying to implement AB tests for my React application, which is built using [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/). I setup Google Optimize tests as `Redirect` type and have another variant, 50/50 traffic split (usual setup). I quickly realized that this only works if I refresh a page, because if I click on a menu item, which has relative path and utilizes [GatsbyJS Link](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/), Google Optimize doesn't do anything, but if I reload the page, it activates.

Example of relative path in my website:

```
<a class="text-black hover:text-teal text-small font-medium px-3" href="/features/">Features</a>
```

Anyone had same issue and found a solution?

Comment: One of the work around is to push the "optimize.activate" event from componentDidMount method or using "useEffect" to push this event manually. For my react application, I triggered an customized event from react component when it is ready and then have the event listener running in google optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "Advanced Redirect"? In there, you have the option to start the test based on link parameters and various paths. Or you could start the experiment when a user clicks on the link, using Javascript as Optimize supports this.

You could check [this Google Optimize Redirect Test](https://analyticshelp.io/blog/google-optimize-redirect-test-qa/) article as it explains this in more detail.